# Best way to quote translated text and add original text, references in footnote

Tags: biblatex, citing, csquotes, translate

I use currently the `csquotes` package for quoting a translated text in the main text of my document. I want also to add original text, original reference and reference of the translation in the footnote.

The idea will be to obtain in the footnote `<< ORIGNAL TEXT >>, (shortRef, p. XX), translation from ShortRef p. YY` and to build a new command such as `\quotetxtTrans{Translated text}{keyTranslatedRef}{pageTrans}{ORIGINAL TEXT}{keyOriginal}{Page YY}`

The command propose by `csquotes` proposed to deal with reference but not multiples references and specific associated footnote. Is there any solution to build it efficiently with `csquotes`or with another package.

I have started to find a solution but it is not working as expected.

**MNWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay = true]{csquotes}
\makeatletter \XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \french@punctguillend = {\xpg@unskip\nobreakspace}

\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@ARTICLE{articleb,
  author = {Nom, Prenom},
  title = {Translated text},
  journal = {hein},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {8},
  pages = {40--110}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\SetCiteCommand{\footcite}

  \begin{document}
%%not working
\hyphenblockcquote{french}[\hyphenquote{german}{Daß ich aus einer Gemeinschaft ausgeschlossen war, ohne zu einer andern zu gehören, daß ich also schon in meiner frühesten Kindheit jenseits der Gemeinden stand, von keiner abgestempelt, als isoliertes, einsames Individuum – das bestimmte meine Haltung und mein Schicksal für das ganze Leben. Ob das für mich ein Glück oder ein Unglück geworden ist, soll im Ablauf dieser Lebensgeschichte offenbar werden. Wenn es, wie mir heute scheint, letztlich ein Glück war, so wurde es ein langes Leben hindurch mit dem schwersten Leid bezahlt}, p. ]{article}{Etre exclu d'une communauté sans faire partie d'une autre, me trouver dès ma petite enfance par-delà les paroisses, catalogué par aucune car individu isolé et seul: voilà ce qui détermina mon attitude et mon destin pour l'ensemble de ma vie. Fut-ce pour moi une chance ou une malchance, c'est ce qui doit apparaître au cours de ce récit de vie. Si j'ai aujourd'hui l'impression que ce fut finalement une chance, je n'en ai pas moins payé le prix fort toute ma vie.}

\hyphenblockcquote{french}[\hyphenquote{german}{Daß ich aus einer Gemeinschaft ausgeschlossen war, ohne zu einer andern zu gehören, daß ich also schon in meiner frühesten Kindheit jenseits}, p. ]{article}{Etre exclu d'une communauté sans faire partie d'une autre, me trouver dès ma petite enfance par-delà les paroisses, catalogué par aucune nalement une chance, je n'en ai pas moins payé le prix fort toute ma vie.}

\hyphenblockquote{french}{Etre exclu d'une communauté sans faire partie d'une autre, me trouver dès ma petite enfance par-delà les paroisses, catalogué par aucune car individu isolé et seul: voilà ce qui détermina mon attitude et mon destin pour l'ensemble de ma vie. Fut-ce pour moi une chance ou une malchance, c'est ce qui doit apparaître au cours de ce récit de vie. Si j'ai aujourd'hui l'impression que ce fut finalement une chance, je n'en ai pas moins payé le prix fort toute ma vie. \footnote{\footcite[\hyphenquote{german}{Daß ich aus einer Gemeinschaft ausgeschlossen war, ohne zu einer andern zu gehören, daß ich also schon in meiner frühesten Kindheit jenseits der Gemeinden stand, von keiner abgestempelt, als isoliertes, einsames Individuum – das bestimmte meine Haltung und mein Schicksal für das ganze Leben. Ob das für mich ein Glück oder ein Unglück geworden ist, soll im Ablauf dieser Lebensgeschichte offenbar werden. Wenn es, wie mir heute scheint, letztlich ein Glück war, so wurde es ein langes Leben hindurch mit dem schwersten Leid bezahlt}, p. ][]{article}\footcite{articleb}}}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: I assume a command would also need to know the language of the original and the translation (in your example `french` and `german`), or should one or more of these be hard-coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is

```
% {<translated text>}{<translated language>}{<entrykey translated work>}{<page translated work>}{<original text>}{<original language>}{<entrykey original>}{<page original>}
\newcommand{\quotetxtTrans}[8]{%
  \renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\mkbibfootnote{##1}}%
  \hyphenblockquote{#2}[{\hyphenquote{#6}{#5} \parencite[#8]{#7} \cite[translation from][#4]{#3}}]{#1}%
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay = true]{csquotes}
\makeatletter \XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \french@punctguillend = {\xpg@unskip\nobreakspace}

\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@ARTICLE{articleb,
  author = {Nom, Prenom},
  title = {Translated text},
  journal = {hein},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {8},
  pages = {40--110}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


% {<translated text>}{<translated language>}{<entrykey translated work>}{<page translated work>}{<original text>}{<original language>}{<entrykey original>}{<page original>}
\newcommand{\quotetxtTrans}[8]{%
  \renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\mkbibfootnote{##1}}%
  \hyphenblockquote{#2}[{\hyphenquote{#6}{#5} \parencite[#8]{#7} translated from \cite[#4]{#3}}]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\quotetxtTrans{E}{french}{articleb}{3}{D}{german}{article}{5}

\quotetxtTrans{Etre exclu d'une communauté sans faire partie d'une autre, me trouver dès ma petite enfance par-delà les paroisses, catalogué par aucune car individu isolé et seul: voilà ce qui détermina mon attitude et mon destin pour l'ensemble de ma vie. Fut-ce pour moi une chance ou une malchance, c'est ce qui doit apparaître au cours de ce récit de vie. Si j'ai aujourd'hui l'impression que ce fut finalement une chance, je n'en ai pas moins payé le prix fort toute ma vie.}{french}{articleb}{3}{Daß ich aus einer Gemeinschaft ausgeschlossen war, ohne zu einer andern zu gehören, daß ich also schon in meiner frühesten Kindheit jenseits der Gemeinden stand, von keiner abgestempelt, als isoliertes, einsames Individuum – das bestimmte meine Haltung und mein Schicksal für das ganze Leben. Ob das für mich ein Glück oder ein Unglück geworden ist, soll im Ablauf dieser Lebensgeschichte offenbar werden. Wenn es, wie mir heute scheint, letztlich ein Glück war, so wurde es ein langes Leben hindurch mit dem schwersten Leid bezahlt}{german}{article}{5}
\end{document}
```

[image: cropped output]